# PHP error 500 with no errors previously

Tags: php

Have a PHP script that worked just fine, I haven't touched it in a week, I tried it again today and now I just get an error.  Not sure what is causing the error, I have chmoded the php so it should work fine.

```
<head>
    <title>Information Gathered</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php 

    echo "<p>Data Processed!</p>";

    $song = $_POST['song'];
    $artist = $_POST['artist'];
    $album = $_POST['album'];       
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];

    echo $song . "</br>";
    echo $artist . "</br>";
    echo $album . "</br>";
    echo $year . "</br>";
    echo $genre . "</br>";

    DEFINE ('DB_USER', '*****');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '*****');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '******');

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
    mysqli_connect_error());

    $sql = "insert into music (song, artist, album, year genre)
            values('$song', '$artist', '$album', '$year', '$genre',)";
    $dbc->query($sql)
    echo "<p> Data Entered!!!</p>"

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked the log file?

Comment: php code is not an executable. a webserver does **NOT** need a php script to be `chmod +x`, period. and if you get a 500, you go look at the server's error log to find out why. anything else is just random flailing around in the dark. and note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and have sql syntax errors. the query should NEVER have worked as is. you're also simply ASSUMING that the query never fails.

Comment: If thats the case then why did it work EVER?

Comment: This never would have worked. The SQL and PHP are invalid, or you altered the code you pasted. Also why the `@` on the connect were you getting errors there? Better to fix then ignore/hide.

Comment: Well it did work so you must be making an assumption about the code because I know you are wrong about that

Comment: typos in .htaccess files can also cause server error 500

Comment: I don't think I'm using .htcaccess files

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Itoau, no PHP version I know of would run your unterminated lines. Nor would any DB execute that invalid query.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the PHP error but your SQL query has an error

it should be

```
insert into music (song, artist, album, year, genre)
values('$song', '$artist', '$album', '$year', '$genre')
```

your commas are misplaced.

Comment: I changed that, but still the same error, thanks though missed that, weird how it worked with that error in there..

Comment: I've changed everything mentioned in this post, still the same 500 error.